How to create a Test plan from power automate?
I've a flow about power automate that creates a test plan in Azure DevOps, but when open the link show me the error Test Plan not found and I don't understand because I can't open in the board Test Plans in Azure DevOps.
Test Plan created
Open Test Plan
Create a test plan in azure devops from power automate to import test cases that are created as workitems

I can see the same error message when do not have the permission "View work items in this node" on the area path which the test plan is assigned to.

You can go to Project Settings > Project configuration > Areas tab to open the Security hub of the area path to check if the permission "View work items in this node" is "Allow" for you. If not, as the user who is Project Administrators (PA) to help to assign the permission to you. If you are the PA user, you can try to change it to "Allow" for yourself.



Thank you for your answer. I followed your steps and the same thing keeps happening to me. Do you have any other options?

@CarlosLaverde, Do you call the Azure DevOps REST API "Test Plans - Create" in power automate workflow to create the test plan? If you manually call the same API via script or Postman from your local machine, does the same issue exist?

@CarlosLaverde, In the same Azure DevOps project, if you manually create a test plan to the same area path and iteration path on the web UI, can you open the test plan?

HI Bright, I’m going to test with API, because I ran my tests with a task of being able to power automate directly.

Yes, when I created the test plan manually, this I can open.

@CarlosLaverde, Can you provide the URI and request body if the API call that you are using on power automate? In the power automate workflow, do you see any error/warning logs when call the API?
